# Laravel 5.2.12 Folder structure, resource/view has no layout folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm going through this guide:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart

It says to create a layout view in:

```
`resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php`
```

The layout folder doesn't exist. Is it supposed to exist?
There doesn't seem to be a website that shows all of the folder structures and how they differ across different laravel versions.
The closest thing I could find was this https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/structure but that only covers the root and app directories.

Cheers

Comment: This might be something worth submitting as an issue, if it in fact supposed to exist

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just create it.

In the quickstart you'll see the layout being used at a later point like this:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
```

This represents the path after `resources/views` where all slashes `/` are replaced with a dot `.`

You could for example place the layout in the directory `resources/views/my/extra/long/path/app.blade.php`

Then you'd have to use it like this:

```
@extends('my.extra.long.path.app')
```

Comment: Helpful though I have the same problem even after doing the same thing. In my case the layout file works correctly in the dev environment but not in the published environment. I have reposted the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56110012/view-layouts-clientlayout-client-header-not-found

Comment: please define what goes into layouts.app