# View layouts.clientLayout.client_header] not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hi I have this project that is working perfectly on my development environment (Local host) I have published it to a a shared vhost and now I am getting the errors below

```
    ErrorException (E_ERROR)
    View [layouts.clientLayout.client_header] not found. (View: /home/ovzejahb/domains/alphaphotography.co.ke/public_html/book/resources/views/layouts/clientlayout/client_design.blade.php) 
    (View: /home/ovzejahb/domains/alphaphotography.co.ke/public_html/book/resources/views/layouts/clientlayout/client_design.blade.php)


    Previous exceptions
    View [layouts.clientLayout.client_header] not found. (View: /home/ovzejahb/domains/alphaphotography.co.ke/public_html/book/resources/views/layouts/clientlayout/client_design.blade.php) (0)
    View [layouts.clientLayout.client_header] not found. (0)
```

What could I be doing wrong because I have the folder structure exactly like it is in  the development environment

In my home.blade.php that it in the views folder i have this

```
  @extends('layouts.clientLayout.client_design')
  @section('content')
```

and then in the layouts/client layout folder I have the following files

client_design.blade.php

client_footer.blade.php

client_header.blade.php

client_sidebar.blade.php

In the client_design.blade.php file I have the code below for including the header, footer, sidebar and content together

```
    <body>
    <!--Header part-->
    @include('layouts.clientLayout.client_header')
    <!--End Header part-->
    <!--Sidebar part-->
    @include('layouts.clientLayout.client_sidebar')
    <!--End Sidebar part-->
    <!--main-container-part-->
    @yield('content')
    <!--end-main-container-part-->
    <!--Footer part-->
    @include('layouts.clientLayout.client_footer')
    <!--End Footer part-->
    <!--Jquery-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You include the views using `clientLayout` but the error shows the path as `layouts/clientlayout/client_design.blade.php`. It probably works on your local machine because [in Windows, file paths are case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7199074) where as on Linux they are case sensitive.

Try renaming the folder with an uppercase `L` or update your views to the lowercase version.

Comment: I have done all that and even cleared all the cache but still not working

Comment: Did it work in the end? If not, try `php artisan view:clear` and `composer dump-autoload`.